# PHP - Set default year in selection box

Tags: php

I'm instructed to create a select box that allows the user to select a year ranging from the current year - 5 to 2050. The default year needs to be the current year.  Right now the list is starting at 2014 (current year -5).

I'm having trouble making the default year display as 2019 rather than 2014.   We are suppose to use the DateTime object and formats that go with the DateTime class.

I'm including code I also wrote for the select box that allows the user to choose a month. I would appreciate feedback on that as well, if it's appropriate to ask. I also have to create a checkbox that allows the user to select the entire year. I've created the checkbox but do not know how to even begin to code it to select the entire year.

edited to add:  This assignment must be done using only PHP and HTML with some CSS styling.

```html
<section>
    <form id="yearForm" name="yearForm" method="post" action="">
        <label for="select_year">Select the year: </label>
        <?php
        // Sets the default year to be the current year.
        $current_year = date('Y');
        // Year to start available options.
        $earliest_year = ($current_year - 5);
        // Set your latest year you want in the range.
        $latest_year = 2050;

        echo '<select>';
        // Loops over each int[year] from current year, back to the $earliest_year [1950]
        foreach ( range( $earliest_year, $latest_year ) as $i ) {
            // Echos the option with the next year in range.
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.($i === $current_year ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>
    </form>
        <br />
        <br />
    <form id="monthForm" name="monthForm" method="post" action="">
        <label for="month">Select the month: </label>
<!--        <input type=hidden id="month" name=month>-->
                        <select id="month" name="month" >
                            <option value='01'>January</option>
                            <option value='02'>February</option>
                            <option value='03'>March</option>
                            <option value='04'>April</option>
                            <option value='05'>May</option>
                            <option value='06'>June</option>
                            <option value='07'>July</option>
                            <option value='08'>August</option>
                            <option value='09'>September</option>
                            <option value='10'>October</option>
                            <option value='11'>November</option>
                            <option value='12'>December</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <br />
        <label for="whole_year">Show whole year: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="whole_year" name="whole_year" >
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class=inline name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: If you want to use DateTime class: `$date = new DateTime(); $current_year = $date->format('Y');`

Comment: @catcon  I'm not sure how to use the code you've given me.  Do I add $date = new DateTime(); before $current_year in my code above?  And edit my $current_year to look as you have coded in your comment?   I did this and DateTime(); is being flagged as "unhandled/exception" in phpStorm.

Comment: It's just a warning, DateTime() construct might throw an exception when creating an object. Your original question said that you must use only topics covered in class, I reckon you haven't learned about handling exception yet.

Comment: No we haven't.  Did I use the code you suggested correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$i` is an integer and `$current_year` is a string so with strict comparison, `===`, these don't match. Use `==` for your comparison and it should work.

```
($i == $current_year ? ' selected="selected"' : '')
```

https://3v4l.org/k1P7T

For more about this see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Comment: I agree. Read up on your comparison operators, it will save you much time and grief going forward. Official PHP Documentation on them.[Comparison Operators](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) Plus, there's much more convenient and creative ways to write comparisons when you learn how to do all of them.